# How can I make a list still contain its elements even after clearing it?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

How should I go about setting a key to a list in a foreach loop and then reseting aforementioned list so it takes in other values without clearing it.

Here is my code:

```
public static Map<String, List<Integer>> trend(Map<String, List<Integer>> companies){
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
    Map<String, List<Integer>> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
    int difference = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : companies.entrySet()) {
        list = entry.getValue();
        for(int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++) {
            if(i < list.size() - 1) {
            difference = list.get(i+1) - list.get(i);
            list2.add(difference);
            }
        }

    finalMap.put(entry.getKey(), list2);
    list.clear();
    list2.clear();
    }
    return finalMap;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "resetting" a `List`? If you still want the `List` to contain all it's elements, why are you clearing it?

Comment: Is this an [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: You don't need `if` inside for loop. Just change <= to < in loop condition.

Comment: My explanation of this problem is pretty poor, but in laymans terms I'm iterating through a map and since the values are of type List<Integer> I used a list to "save" those values so I could use them later in my for loop. I would like to assign the values I got from the for loop to a new map but after one loop of foreach is completed the lists I used previously still have old values in them. Essentially I'm asking how would I "empty" the list without affecting what was stored in the new map.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to clear that list just remove the call to list.clear() for that list.